# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '-f'

Tags: python, file-io, nltk, tokenize

Please forgive my ignorant question.
I'm in the infant stage of learning Python.
I want to convert Before_text into After_text.

```
<Before_text>
Today, I got up early, so I’m absolutely exhausted. I had breakfast: two slices \n
of cold toast and a disgusting coffee, then I left the house at 8 o’clock still \n
feeling half asleep. Honestly, London’s killing me!
```

```
<After_text>
Today, I got up early, so I’m absolutely exhausted. 
I had breakfast: two slices of cold toast and a disgusting coffee, then I left the house at 8 o’clock still feeling half asleep. 
Honestly, London’s killing me!
```

In fact, regardless of the code, I only need to get this result (After_text).
I used this code:

```
import sys, fileinput
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize

if __name__ == "__main__":
    buf = []

    for line in fileinput.input():
        if line.strip() != "":
            buf += [line.strip()]
            sentences = sent_tokenize(" ".join(buf))

            if len(sentences) > 1:
                buf = sentences[1:]

                sys.stdout.write(sentences[0] + '\n')

    sys.stdout.write(" ".join(buf) + "\n")
```

The following error is produced:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-ef8b2fcb97ad> in <module>()
      5     buf = []
      6 
----> 7     for line in fileinput.input():
      8         if line.strip() != "":
      9             buf += [line.strip()]

-------------------------1 frames--------------------------------------------------
/usr/lib/python3.7/fileinput.py in _readline(self)
    362                     self._file = self._openhook(self._filename, self._mode)
    363                 else:
--> 364                     self._file = open(self._filename, self._mode)
    365         self._readline = self._file.readline  # hide FileInput._readline
    366         return self._readline()

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '-f'
```

What is causing this error? Where is a bug in this code?
And how and where do I load and save a text file?
Please teach me~

Comment: What you can do is read the file and iterate over the lines using for loop

Comment: It looks as though the command line you are using to run this program includes `< -f` which means "take input from the file called -f" but there is no such file. Did you maybe mean something like `< myfile.txt`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use [fileinput.input()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html) you should provide input filenames as arguments (`sys.argv`), simple example, if you have `cat.py` as follows

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input():
    print(line, end='')
```

and text files `file1.txt`, `file2.txt`, `file3.txt` in same catalog then usage is:

```
python cat.py file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
```

Comment: I don't really need the main code above. All I need is these.
1. Load a text file.
2. Remove any row breaks at the end of the line and reconnect them.
3. A new sentence begins with a new line.
4. Save the translated text.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, `fileinput.input()` is a shortcut that takes things from the command line input and tries to open them one at a time, or if nothing is specified it uses `stdin` as its input.

Please show us how you are invoking your script. I suspect you have an `-f` in there that the function is trying to open.